# how to define base URL in the dev server for react-scripts start call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx

I have a primary php server. I have to run the reactjs dev server created from `yarn start` within a directory `/reactive` within the php site (using nginx proxy_pass).

But I cannot set the root of the node server to be `/reactive`. It sets it to `/` and therefore just the html file loads and tries to load bundle from `/static/js/bundle.js` which will fail. If it were `/reactive/static/js/bundle.js` it would have worked. How to achieve this configuration?

```
"react": "16.8.1"
"react-scripts": "2.1.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

at yow package.json in the `npm start` script and a PUBLIC_URL variable

```json
"homepage": "/yow-path",
"scripts":{
   "start": "PUBLIC_URL=/reactive node start.js"
}
```

Comment: keep keep what you had, just add that before it

Comment: Has no effect. The browser still opens as `localhost:3000` while it should open as `localhost:3000/path/`

Comment: The script bundle is still loaded from `/static/js/bundle.js` but should have been `/path/static/js/bundle.js`

Comment: add a homepage as well

Comment: i have tried this. does not work for debug mode.